# UITextField field should not clear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` when I enter the text and go back to the previous view the string in the text field gets disappeared when I get back to the view where I have this `UITextfield`. How to make the string in the `UITextfield` to stay without getting cleared even after switching views and unless I change the value by entering it ?

Comment: you have to store this entered value of textfiled and set when you switch between view's.

Comment: How to store that value in text field without clearing @NitinGohel

Comment: you can save the textfield value in NSUSerDefaults.

Comment: Store that string value in nsuserdeaults.

Answer (score 0):

You can have separate save and load method for each uitextview or you can store them in json file. Input : Textfield.text, Section : which textfield do you want to save and load. Then you just call the load method in the ViewDidLoad.

```
- (void) saveTemporary:(NSString *)input :(NSString *)section
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:input forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"textfield_%@",section]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

-(NSString *)loadTemporary :(NSString *)section
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadingString = [defaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"textfield_%@",section]];
    return  loadingString;
}
```